# Relay modem DHCP or fake MACs for multiple IPs?

Tags: networking, router, vmware-workstation

I have a Arris TG862 cable modem and this modem have 4 Ethernet ports and each of those ports will give you a valid Dynamic IP, not a IP like 192, 10., etc...

Up to how many IP's it can serve without complaining I have no idea, but those 4 ports will definitively serve me a dynamic IP any time I plug anything in.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to retrieve multiple IP's from a single network card on windows 7?

I know its possible with Linux and perhaps there is a simple way to achieve the same on windows?

The goal is to use those IP's on VMs from the host.

Much alike what is being done on the update of this answer https://superuser.com/a/344738/49575 for windows.

Comment: Your question is about virtualization, so you should specify, what virtualization platform you use and how. So your question should rather be: `How To Make [xxxx] Use My Router’s DHCP to get an IP` where `[xxx]` is the name of your virtualization software.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I am using VMWare Workstation 12, but the host requests for an IP from the modem already, and the VMWare assigns to it self 192.x.x.x using its internal network management. I know I can set the network device of a VM as bridge from the main device but would that be sufficient?

Comment: The VM guests will obtain their own IP from the DHCP server, they just need to bridge to the ethernet adapter.

Comment: @Adrien thanks for confirming I will try that once I can.

Comment: You might want to get a router anyway, so you can manage a centralized set of firewall rules. Because you get multiple public IPs, you could even create a true DMZ.

Comment: @DanielB well I don't really need a firewall for what I am using it for and I do have a router, but in the end I only have 1 network device to plug it in for the VMs in the host, so I don't see much advantage for it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible **, you simply need to setup bridge networking to virtual interfaces.

VMWare comes with bridging when installed. You just need to configure the VM's to use it on the primary ethernet adapter connected directly to the physical switch.

** This *may* not be possible if your ISP limits the number of IP addresses to one per port (not common).

If you want to do the same with Windows directly (no VM software), you still need a third party driver (unless you're running Windows Server).

See this answer on ServerFault: [Any way to make a virtual bridged network adapter in windows? Like VMware has?](https://serverfault.com/questions/279390/any-way-to-make-a-virtual-bridged-network-adapter-in-windows-like-vmware-has)

Comment: Definitively interesting will check on that.